# How do i get two ul´s parallel centered?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a problem centering two ul´s parallel. I´ve tried everything, margin 0 auto, text-align centered and so on... I basically want the ul displayed inline and centered. I know thats not possible that way so...

```
<div class="html">
 <ul>
  <li><img src="pic1.png"></li>
  <li><img src="pic2.png"></li>
  <li><img src="pic3.png"></li>
 </ul>

<div class="php">
 <ul>
  <li><img src="pic1.png"></li>
  <li><img src="pic2.png"></li>
  <li><img src="pic3.png"></li>
 </ul>




.html ul, .php ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.html li, .php li {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
```

appreciate your help...

Comment: can you show your expected output as image? Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/ukg8c1qd/?

Comment: yes centered, but also the div´s next to each other... is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukg8c1qd/4/)**

```
.html,  .php {
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
     margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 40px 0;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.html ul, .php ul {   
    list-style-type: none;   
    text-align:center;     
    border:1px solid gray;
}

.html li, .php li {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}
```

In CSS I specified `width (50%)` for the outer container of `<UL>` as per your HTML code and gave `float` to get output side by side.

**HTML structure:**

```
<div class="html">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="pic1.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="pic2.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="pic3.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="php">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="pic1.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="pic2.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="pic3.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```